# asp.net radio button on click event without page load

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, radio-button

My problem is pretty simple, but I am not able to fix it.

I have 2 radio buttons and a hidden text label. Once the first radio button is clicked, I want to show the hidden label, and when the second radio button is clicked, I want to hide it again - all this without reloading the page.

I am hoping this can be achieved by JavaScript, but unfortunately I don't know how.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks Piyush.. It works for me... really its a great control...

Comment: Welcome, can you please flag my comment as a useful comment

Comment: am really sorry, this is my first post on stackoverflow, and i couldn't find flag on your post ;-P

Answer (score 1):

Try the following simple example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio][name=GName]').change(function() {
        if (this.value == '1') {
           $("#label").text("Yes");
        }
        else if (this.value == '2') {
           $("#label").text("No");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="GName" value="1"> Yes</input>
<input type="radio" name="GName" value="2"> No</input>
<p> <span id="label">  </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to bind an onlick-Event handler

```
   $('#firstcheckbox').click(function() {
      //code goes here   
   });

   $('#secondcheckbox').click(function() {
      //code goes here   
   });
```